# не могу понять в чём ошибка нахождение минимума в дереве

Tags: c++

int Min(node* node)
{
if (node->left != NULL) {
cout << "В дереве нет элементов\n" << endl;

```
    return Min(node->left);
}
else {
    return node->info;
}
}
```

в чём проблема почему он не находит минимум

фото вывода в консоли :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: if (node->left != NULL) {    cout << "В дереве нет элементов\n" << endl; || Возможно стоит заменить **!=** на **==**

Comment: пока нечего не изменилось

Comment: Посмотрел получше. во-первых стоит поменять return Min(...) и return node->info местами (при этом вернуть сравнение на !=). Также отправьте функцию нахождения минимума дерева, возможно ошибка там. Также напишите тип дерева, если это важно. И я не понимаю, в деревьях существуют только левые ветки?

Comment: вот структура дерева ```struct node
{
    int info;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    int balance;
};
```

Comment: для полного понимания я вам скину целый код - https://pastebin.com/hVucNfRH

Answer (score 1):

Замени Min на

```
  int Min(node* node)
    {
        if (node->left != NULL) {
            return Min(node->left);      
        }
        else {
            return node->info;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: после добавление не работает не выводит число

Comment: cout << "Мин значение"<<endl; Min(root); Вы написали такой код. Как он вообще раньше число выводил? cout << "Мин значение"<< Min(root) << endl;